# Details Scroll area's setwidget function shows a toolbar

Tags: c++, qt

I have a scrollarea and I'm setting a basic QWidget as its widget, However when I do this I get a toolbar on top of the widget I just set;

[image: The Toolbar]

This is the slot I use to create the QWidget and set it to the scroll area, this happens during runtime and the qwidget is deleted and recreated repeatedly during runtime.

```
void SlotCreateDetailsWidget()
{
    if (m_DetailsWidget == nullptr)
    {
        m_DetailsWidget = new DetailsWidget(); // QWidget
        m_Ui->DetailsScrollArea->setWidget(m_DetailsWidget);
        m_DetailsWidget->show();
    }
}
```

What do I need to do to get rid of this toolbar?

Answer (score 0):

From https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html :

> A widget without a parent widget is always an independent window
> (top-level widget).

What you see depends on the underlying windowing system but you can customize it up to a certain point with `void QWidget::setWindowFlag(Qt::WindowType flag, bool on = true)` for example. You can also look at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-windowflags-example.html.